# How does ROS knows which node is publishing?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was looking at the beginner's  Publisher node boilerplate code from the [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) and I was wondering:

How does ROS knows which node is the publisher of a message?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

I see the creation of a `chatter` Topic and `talker` node, so, how does `pub.publish` knows which topic is publishing and if `pub.publish` doesn't need to know, how does rosmaster knows?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345168/how-does-ros-knows-which-node-is-publishing?/) by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2020-02-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2020-02-26**:
What exactly do you want to know?

Your first question "how does ROS knows which node is the publisher" is about the client library. In this case this is `rospy`. Here the node is registered and also the publisher with the topic is registered. Eventually the [master](http://wiki.ros.org/Master) handles setting up the communication with nodes that have subscriptions on this topic.

Your second question "how does `pub.publish` know to which topic it is publishing" is more straightforward. When the publisher is created, the topic is given as an argument and publisher object is stored in the variable `pub`. When you call `pub.publish` later on, the object still knows what its topic is.

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-02-26**:
Dear Bonestroo,

If I was to create 2 nodes in the same py script:

```
 rospy.init_node('talker1', anonymous=True)
 rospy.init_node('talker2', anonymous=True)
```

with all other the same, which one would be the node publishing data?

**Comment by [Wilco Bonestroo](https://answers.ros.org/users/30578/wilco-bonestroo/) on 2020-02-27**:
Hi, Now I see your question. There can be only one node per python process. According to the [documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown) "You can only have one node in a rospy process, so you can only call rospy.init_node() once."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Because you use rospy.init_node() before sending the actual message, this will communicate with the roscore of the node's existence. The publisher must have an initialized node before being able to to publish. Try removing the "rospy.init_node('talker', anonymous=True)" and it will fail to publish.

---

Originally posted by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) with karma: 525 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [John999991](https://answers.ros.org/users/39040/john999991/) on 2020-02-26**:
So, I cannot initialize 2 nodes from the same .py file?

**Comment by [bob-ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/45543/bob-ros/) on 2020-02-26**:
It is not intended to have multiple nodes in one rospy program https://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Initialization%20and%20Shutdown#Initializing_your_ROS_Node